# how can I join these tables and get the desired results

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table which contains some licenses and for distinct license there exists a record based on networks
like eg: license 12345 has records for network('101','102','108')
now i want to find out , out of networks ('101','102','108','113','114'), which all networks my license is missing, after this we need to copy the data of existing license to the ,missing licenses for all the five networks?

I am already using a script:
take a look

```
select license, count(*) data, network nt1 from x_pns_address
where network  in ('101','102', '108', '113', '114')
and license in ('110438','150275')
group by license, network
into temp sherin_1;

select distinct license, '101' netw from x_pns_address
where license in ('110438','150275')
into temp table1;

insert into  table1 select distinct license, 
'102' netw from x_pns_address
where license in ('110438','150275');
insert into  table1 select distinct license,
'108' netw from x_pns_address
where license in ('110438','150275');
insert into table1  select distinct license, 
'113' netw from x_pns_address
where license in ('110438','150275');
insert into  table1  select distinct license, 
'114' netw from x_pns_address
where license in ('110438','150275');

select distinct a.nt1,a.license,
b.netw  from sherin_1 a, table1 b
where a.license = b.license
and  a.nt1 <> b.netw
 ;
```

which is fetching me this:

```
 nt1 license      netw

   101 150275       102
   101 150275       108
   101 150275       113
   101 150275       114
   102 110438       101
   102 110438       108
   102 110438       113
   102 110438       114
   102 150275       101
   102 150275       108
   102 150275       113
   102 150275       114
   108 110438       101
   108 110438       102
   108 110438       113
   108 110438       114
   108 150275       101
   108 150275       102
   108 150275       113
   108 150275       114
   113 110438       101
   113 110438       102
   113 110438       108
   113 110438       114
   113 150275       101
   113 150275       102
   113 150275       108
   113 150275       114
   114 110438       101
   114 110438       102
   114 110438       108
   114 110438       113
```

Comment: It is MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: table name is x_pns_network.

Comment: You can use join......try this select distinct a.nt1,a.license,
b.netw  from sherin_1 a JOIN table1 b ON a.license = b.license and  a.nt1 <> b.netw ;

Comment: gofr1 -we work on both!

Comment: piyush : your query gives me the same output , i just mentioned.

anything else in return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use this:

I create table with dummy data.

```
CREATE TABLE #x_pns_address (
    network int,
    license int
)

INSERT INTO #x_pns_address VALUES
(101,12345),
(102,12345),
(108,12345),
(101,54321),
(102,54321),
(108,54321),
(113,54321),
(114,54321),
(101,98765),
(108,98765)
```

As you can see license `54321` has all 5 networks, and `12345`, `98765` got 2 and 3.

Then we run:

```
INSERT INTO #x_pns_address
SELECT  p1.license,
        n.network
FROM (
    SELECT license --Here we get all licenses that missed any of the
    FROM #x_pns_address   --given numbers
    WHERE network IN (101,102,108,113,114)
    GROUP BY license
    HAVING COUNT(network) < 5
    ) as p1
CROSS JOIN ( --Cartesian join with license numbers we need
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (101),(102),(108),(113),(114)) as t(network)
) as n
LEFT JOIN #x_pns_address x --and here we get only those that are not in main table
    ON x.network = n.network and x.license = p1.license
WHERE x.license  IS NULL
```

And in the `#x_pns_address` we add 5 rows with missing networks for licenses `12345`, `98765`:

```
license network
12345   113
12345   114
98765   102
98765   113
98765   114
```

Comment: Did you try solution from my answer? Just curious :)

Comment: It's great! My pleasure! :)

Comment: hi gofr1,the script finally ran with minor changes i suppose,thanks in tons. :)

I have some further queries,will you be able to help?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, was on vacation, can not reply. Of course SOreadytohelp :)

Comment: Hi gofr1, actually this went well for networks that had same no. of records,
suppose there is a license 16079 which has already existing records for network 101,102,108,113. The no. of records for network 101 =3,102=3,108=2,113=2,
while i applied this logic with some minor changes,i got the records copied for network 114,that means i got 3 records for 114, bt i obviously need 3 records for both 108 and 113 also.

could u help me with something simpler,bcz i am working on applying a loop,but that would complicate things.

Could u please find a simpler solution?????? :")

Comment: So, for 101,102,114 number of records is 3 and they all got the same collection of license? And you need to add 1 missing license to 108 and 113 networks?

Comment: No no not missing license,bt each license has records say like license has a status,licenseid,addressid like that.

So for 101,102 there were already 3 records existing nd we copied for 114 by our code,
for 108,113 there were already 2-2 records existing simlutanaeously,bt we need all 3 records existing for 108,113 as well

Comment: I suggest you to post new question... it is pretty complicated to understand without samples of data and description of logic to generate output you need.